# Created Bar Chart but Cannot read json data into it in html, Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, function, charts

*After checking some related questions, couldn't find any good answers, So that why I am posting my question here. I have created a bar chart and hard coded all the values and the charts works fine, But instead of hard Coding I want to read my data from Json file(data.json) which is external file. Can I get some help with this. Thanks in Advance. *

**Bar Chart Image**
[image]

**data.json file**

```
[
  {
    "date": "2016-12-1",
    "high": 7,
    "medium": 18,
    "low": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-12-13",
    "high": 1,
    "medium": 27,
    "low": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-12-20",
    "high": 1,
    "medium": 11,
    "low": 3
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-01-06",
    "high": 1,
    "medium": 22,
    "low": 2
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-01-11",
    "high": 1,
    "medium": 16,
    "low": 2
  }]
```

**My Html code:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Changa+One|Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i,800" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h2> My first Bar Chart.... </h2>
  </header>

    <div class="container">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
    <div>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
 <script src="js/chart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Finally my Javascript code:**

```
var myChart = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
//Global options
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Lato';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 16;
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#777';


//new Chart creates a new chart object
var threadScoreChart = new Chart(myChart, {
   type: 'bar',  // bar type chart
   data: {
     labels: ['13 Dec', '20 Dec', '27 Dec', '03 Jan', '10 Jan', '17 Jan', '24 Jan',
             '31 Jan','07 Feb','14 Feb', '21 Feb', '28 Feb', '12 April'],
     datasets: [
       {
        label: 'High',
        data: [3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5],
        backgroundColor:'rgba(251, 153, 148, 0.6)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#777',
        hoverBorderWidth: 3,
        hoverBorderColor: '#000'
     }, {
        label: 'Medium',
        data: [18, 27, 11, 22, 16, 33, 29, 28, 24, 37, 37, 47, 48],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(251, 217, 158, 0.6)', //yelloworange color

     }, {
       label: 'Low',
       data: [0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,1, 1, 1, 1, 5],
       backgroundColor: 'rgba(135, 175, 190, 0.6)', //light blue
     }]
   },

   // Configuration options go here
   options: {
     scaleBeginAtZero: true,
                      scaleStartValue: 0,
                      scales: {
                          yAxes: [{
                              ticks: {
                                  beginAtZero:true
                              }
                          }]
                      },
        title: {
          display:true,
          text: 'Scores in 2017 and 2018',
          fontSize: 25
        },
        subtitle: {
          text: "check out the z-axis movement"
        },
        layout:{
          padding: {
            left:50,
            right:0,
            bottom:0,
            top:0
          }
        },
        legend: {
          display: true,
           position: "right",
           fullWidth: true,
           labels: {
             boxWidth: 16,
             fontSize: 16
           },
            header: {
            text: 'Legend Header',
            fontSize: 16
          }
        },
        item: {
          cursor: 'pointer'
        },
        tooltips: {
          enabled:false  //when hover there will be no tooltips showing.
        }

   } //options ends

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to *read data from Json file*, don't include the json in a script tag,

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
```

use ajax to get the data instead...

```
function getData() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'data.json',
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function (jsonData) {
    // --> jsonData
  });
}
```

or if don't want to include jquery...

```
function getData() {
  var jsonRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  jsonRequest.open('get', 'so_q0.txt');
  jsonRequest.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
  jsonRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  jsonRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (jsonRequest.readyState === 4) {
      if (jsonRequest.status === 200) {
        // --> JSON.parse(jsonRequest.responseText)
      }
    }
  };
  jsonRequest.send();
}
```

also recommend waiting for the page to load, before drawing the chart.

once you have the json,
you can use the `map` method to extract separate arrays for the chart...

```
getValues(jsonData, 'date')
getValues(jsonData, 'high')
getValues(jsonData, 'medium')
getValues(jsonData, 'low')

function getValues(jsonData, key) {
  return jsonData.map(function (row) {
    return row[key];
  });
}
```

---

see following working snippet,
the data has been hard-coded for example purposes,
the data request will actually fail in this snippet,
just remove the `else` clause and you should be good to go...

```js
window.onload = getData;

function getData() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'data.json',
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function (jsonData) {
    drawChart(jsonData);
  }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    drawChart([{
      "date": "2016-12-01",
      "high": 7,
      "medium": 18,
      "low": 0
    }, {
      "date": "2016-12-13",
      "high": 1,
      "medium": 27,
      "low": 0
    }, {
      "date": "2016-12-20",
      "high": 1,
      "medium": 11,
      "low": 3
    }, {
      "date": "2017-01-06",
      "high": 1,
      "medium": 22,
      "low": 2
    }, {
      "date": "2017-01-11",
      "high": 1,
      "medium": 16,
      "low": 2
    }]);
  });
}

function drawChart(jsonData) {
  Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Lato';
  Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 16;
  Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#777';

  var myChart = $('#myChart').get(0).getContext('2d');

  var threadScoreChart = new Chart(myChart, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: getValues(jsonData, 'date'),
      datasets: [{
        label: 'High',
        data: getValues(jsonData, 'high'),
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(251, 153, 148, 0.6)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#777',
        hoverBorderWidth: 3,
        hoverBorderColor: '#000'
      }, {
        label: 'Medium',
        data: getValues(jsonData, 'medium'),
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(251, 217, 158, 0.6)'
      }, {
        label: 'Low',
        data: getValues(jsonData, 'low'),
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(135, 175, 190, 0.6)'
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scaleBeginAtZero: true,
      scaleStartValue: 0,
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero:true
          }
        }]
      },
      title: {
        display:true,
        text: 'Scores in 2017 and 2018',
        fontSize: 25
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'check out the z-axis movement'
      },
      layout: {
        padding: {
          left:50,
          right:0,
          bottom:0,
          top:0
        }
      },
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'right',
        fullWidth: true,
        labels: {
          boxWidth: 16,
          fontSize: 16
        },
        header: {
          text: 'Legend Header',
          fontSize: 16
        }
      },
      item: {
        cursor: 'pointer'
      },
      tooltips: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  });
}

function getValues(jsonData, key) {
  return jsonData.map(function (row) {
    var months = [
      'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
      'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
    ];
    var value = row[key];
    if (key === 'date') {
      value = value.split('-');
      value = value[2] + '-' + months[value[1] - 1];
    }
    return value;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lots for the help, I will try to use Ajax and hope that it works for me. Thanks again!

Comment: How can I format the date, for example instead of displaying the date like this: 2016-12-1 ( in labels) i want to display like this: 01-Jan. I have tried by using ' var json = JSON.stringify(jsonData.key == 'date'); ' but nothing seems to work. Will Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Thanks again, the date works :)                                                                  But one thing is not clear for me, can you please explain: what does this do: value = value[2] + ' ' + months[value[1] -1];    ------- Why  it starts at  index 2    'value[2]'

Comment: the split methods creates an array of the date parts, `value[2]` is the value for the day

Answer (score 0):

The JSON file data structure needs to be analyzed to see how it can be converted or read using an algorithm so its data can can be placed in the object passed as the second parameter to `new Chart`:

1. File (array) entries are objects with a date property and additional properties providing point values for each of three bar graphs on that date.
2. Chart parameters want an array of date strings used as labels, and and a separate array of values for each of the bar charts to plot.

I worked through converting the data structure to illustrate the first step in taking that approach, by taking the file data and producing an array of chart labels along with three data set arrays:

```js
var fileResponse = 
'[{"date":"2016-12-1","high":7,"medium":18,"low":0},{"date":"2016-12-13","high":1,"medium":27,"low":0},{"date":"2016-12-20","high":1,"medium":11,"low":3},{"date":"2017-01-06","high":1,"medium":22,"low":2},{"date":"2017-01-11","high":1,"medium":16,"low":2}]';

var fileData = JSON.parse(fileResponse); // same data as in post

// restructure the data:

const fileSetNames = ["high", "medium", "low"];
const chartSetNames =["High", "Medium", "Low"];
const months_en = [
        "Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun",
        "Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"
];
function prettyLabel(label) {
    return chartSetNames[ fileSetNames.indexOf(label)];
}
function prettyDate( fileDate) {
    fileDate = fileDate.split("-");
    let month = fileDate[1];
    if( month[0]== "0") {
        month = month[1]; // remove leading zero
    }
    return months_en[month-1] + " " + fileDate[2];
}

var chartData = fileData.reduce(
    ( outData, inData) => {
        outData.labels.push( prettyDate(inData.date));
        for( var label of fileSetNames) {
            var Label = prettyLabel(label);
            outData[Label].push( inData[label]);
        }
        return outData;
    },
    { labels: [], High: [], Medium: [], Low: [] }
);

//  show chartData structure:
console.log( chartData);
```

This is subject to rewriting as required in an application: data series names and date reformatting are hard coded, and style requirements may differ.

The restructured data still needs to be inserted into the second parameter passed to `Charts`, which I leave for you to continue with - it's called work :D. Good luck.